# br -algorithm AgeEstimation -enroll me.jpg you.jpg metadata.csv doesn't work

Tags: command-line-tool, openbr

I try to get age estimation from two pictures but it doesn't work. 
The command is:

```
br -algorithm AgeEstimation -enroll me.jpg you.jpg metadata.csv
```

The problem is that in metadata.csv it write only you.jpg result.
I try

```
br -algorithm AgeEstimation -EnrollAll -enroll me.jpg you.jpg metadata.csv
```

and same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made more research and i found this solution.

```
 br -algorithm AgeEstimation -enroll folder metadata.csv
```

br expect a collection which can be either a folder with photos, even a folder with folder of photos. It can make recursive search after photos from folder.
So enjoy this feature.